# NavDrawer is not giving touches to other views

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I want to create a drawer activity which contains a image. Now I want that the parent of image view, i.e. content_main2, which is relative layout, should listen to touch events like swipe and fling. but it is only receiving touch down.

My main activity is a Nav Drawer Activity.

My Main Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    RelativeLayout content_main2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        content_main2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_main2);

        final GestureDetector gdt=new GestureDetector(this,onGestureListener);

        content_main2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Touched",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });    

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {    
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {    
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {    
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {    
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {    
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }    

    private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener onGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("gestureDebug333", "doubleTapped:" + e);
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("gestureDebug333", "doubleTappedEvent:" + e);

            return super.onDoubleTapEvent(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.i("gestureDebug333", "onDown:" + e);   
            return super.onDown(e);    
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {    

            Log.i("gestureDebug333", "flinged:" + e1 + "---" + e2);
            Log.i("gestureDebug333", "fling velocity:" + velocityX + "---" + velocityY);
            if (e1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e1.getX() > (e2.getX() + 300)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "flinged right to left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (e1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && e2.getX() > (e1.getX() + 300)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "flinged left to right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
            super.onShowPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }
    };
}
```

My Activity xml(activity_main2.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.my_workstation.fabbystore1.Main2Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.my_workstation.fabbystore1.Main2Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added,
`android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

android:focusable="true"

android:clickable="true"` 
 in content_main2 (RelativeLayout).

 Everything is working now.